# php plug-in for developers on firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there any plug-in for firefox that is usefull for PHP development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one I've used before : [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/)

The beauty of that is you can use FireBug console to debug your php code, which I reckon is better than echoing everything to html :)

If you want general web development plugins there there are many, some of the most valuable ones:

- FireBug
- Web Developer
- HttpFox
- PageSpeed from Google

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) with Fire PHP

For your ajax request and javascript errors and everything